# Python find and replace numbers based on pattern

Tags: python, parsing

I've got a string and I'd like to find and replace some numbers in it. I.e., there are multiple repetitions of "v = 324\n" in there, with different values. Now I want to divide all those numbers by `n` (rounded to nearest integer) and save it as a new string.

At the moment I'm using parse package:

```
n = 10
s = "this is v = 2342\n and another v = 231\n and some stuff..."
for r in findall("v = {:d}\\n", s):
    print r
```

This gives me the list of Results, but I don't know how to make changes to the string. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) that takes your matched pattern `samples = {:d}\\n` (which I had to update) and computes it in some way.  Here is a demo:

```
import re

def sampleRounder(match):
    return str(int(float(match.group(1)))) #base=10

s = "this is v = 2342.2\n and another v = 231.003\n and some stuff..."

print(re.sub("v = ([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)\\n", sampleRounder, s))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, great answer and easy to reuse :)

Comment: This truncates instead of rounding to the nearest int, but as long as the OP can figure out how to to do that himself (hint: the `round` builtin does what it says, try `help(round)` for more), this should be all he needs.

Comment: I reread the OP's question and I can see that my sample code was way off of the request. I'll fix it when I get back to a desktop browser, but the idea still holds :)